# In what file does SQL Server Store the configuration data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, configuration, database-internals

Where does SQL Server 2014 store the configuration data? Such as the certificate references for SSL and the size limits and allocations?

Answer (score 2):

Basically there is not a single place where ever configuration can be found.

The more generally used configurations can be found here [Server Configuration Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189631.aspx). But they do not necessarily cover everything that you might want to configure.

For example:  [Enable SSL Encryption for SQL Server using Microsoft Management Console](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316898/how-to-enable-ssl-encryption-for-an-instance-of-sql-server-by-using-microsoft-management-console)

Also you can find some information on size limits and allocations at: [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.120).aspx)

Perhaps these examples will get you started.